# how to customize sync according to selected data only sync framework / trick to do it 

Tags: c#, web-services, microsoft-sync-framework

I am developing an sync database application for one of my client i am done with synchronization but now i stuck at a part that i don`t want to sync complete table i just wana sync dynamically selected record through sync framework

using `sqlce` at client end

Any good link which make some help will also be preferable

i am sync ing some thing like below at server

```
public SyncContext GetChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, SyncSession syncSession)
    {
        return serverSyncProvider.GetChanges(groupMetadata, syncSession);
    }



    public SyncContext ApplyChanges(SyncGroupMetadata groupMetadata, DataSet dataSet, SyncSession syncSession)
    {
        return serverSyncProvider.ApplyChanges(groupMetadata, dataSet, syncSession);
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can add a filter to restrict the rows being synched. Sync Framework however does not support dynamic filtering. Sync framework does synchronization based on incremental syncs of what has changed since the last sync.

for example, assuming you have a customer table and you let a user pick which customer to sync.

you will most likely store the customers that was picked for synching in another table, let's say SelectedCustomer which would store the user id. and the customer id.

when a user adds or removes a customer from his selection, you would update the SelectedCustomer. However, when you sync Customer table, you won't get anything not unless the specific customer record has been changed since the last sync. Even if a customer was added to a specific user, the actual customer record is not updated, no update, no change detected.

Comment: but i love to get an answer which can assist me with some link which alow us to sync data dynamically

Comment: yeap filtering is a good option but my end its a dynamic filtering needed but as you come to more close what i needed i am marking your post as an answer

Answer (score 3):

Here is the article written by JuneT ;)

[Sync Framework Provisioning](http://jtabadero.wordpress.com/2010/09/02/sync-framework-provisioning/)

Go to **Parameter-based Filters** section

JuneT's answer is absolutely correct. The trick is if you select to a row to sync, update that row first before synching (so that tracking table will record the row as updated).

Comment: this blog post applies to the newer sync providers (sqlcesyncprovider/sqlsyncprovider) whereas the code he posted above is for the older sqlceclientsyncprovider/dbserversyncprovider providers that is also used by the Local Database Cache wizard. but the dummy update approach should work with the older provider as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update SelectedCustomer is not enough, the tracking record is syncronized but the real one is not. I had to create a insert/update trigger to update the local_create_peer_timestamp from the master tracking record.